# Method presentViewController does not work on iOS 8.3 after update

Tags: ios, swift

I've just updated Xcode to version 6.3 (with iOS SDK 8.3) and my project - working perfectly on 8.1 and 8.2 - seems to have some issue with the `presentViewController` method.

**Code:**

```
var alert = UIAlertController(title: "\(Percent)%", message: TipsMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:nil))
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Describe the issues you are having.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the issue? I haven't had add issues with presentViewController.

Comment: it works perfectly on IOS8.1 and 8.2,but when i updated new Xcode and my iPhone system to 8.3,my app will crashes to home screen

Comment: Add http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions breakpoint for all exceptions. That will show you more info about the crash.

Comment: Is there anything in the lldb or it just doesn't do anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add this alertController is superclass....**

```
lazy var alertController: UIAlertController = { [weak self] in
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "This is a demo alert", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
        return alert
        }()

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Could you maybe explain what are you trying to solve by this piece of code?

Comment: At this point in your code the view controller's view has only been created but not added to any view hierarchy. If you want to present from that view controller as soon as possible you should do it in viewDidAppear to be safest.

Comment: That looks like a nice argument, but I strongly believe the question says - **it worked on 8.1 & 8.2**. So it worked already and it did already add the VC to the hierarchy. Please refrain from answering questions just by pasting a piece of code without explanation to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Where are you calling this method from? I had an issue where I was attempting to present a modal view controller within the viewDidLoad method. The solution for me was to move this call to the viewDidAppear: method.

My presumption is that the view controller's view is not in the window's view hierarchy at the point that it has been loaded (when the viewDidLoad message is sent), but it is in the window hierarchy after it has been presented (when the viewDidAppear: message is sent).

Comment: I am not the owner of this question, so I have no idea, where it gets called from. But when I took the snippet and pasted it to `viewDidLoad()` in one of my projects, it showed the alert just fine. Even without your suggestion for lazy initialization.