# setting frame in swift doesn't work as expected

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I'm porting an app from Objective-C into pure Swift and I'm facing strange problem.

I've got `AlertView` class which is replacement for standard `UIAlertView` (now `UIAlertController`) for displaying animatable popups. `AlertView` is created in `UIViewController` extension - it's inited with view controller's view frame and added as a subview.

`AlertView` has a property which is a `PopupView`'s instance - custom `UIView` subclass with xib (on Autolayout). This popup should has dynamic height depends on its contents (multiline message label).

Now when I'm trying to animate this popup in `AlertView` class:

- when I set in `PopupView` `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)` - view's height is correct but setting its frame in animation doesn't work as expected - view is sticked to the top left corner
- when I set `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(true)` - animation works as expected BUT view has a size from xib (won't expand according to contents)

What can be wrong here?

EDIT
Showing popup method:

```
private func showPopup(popupView: PopupView)
{
    var beginFrame = popupView.frame
    beginFrame.origin.y = -beginFrame.size.height
    beginFrame.origin.x = self.bounds.size.width/2 - beginFrame.width/2
    popupView.frame = beginFrame

    var endFrame = beginFrame
    endFrame.origin.y = self.bounds.size.height/2 - endFrame.size.height/2

    popupView.hidden = false
    DLog(beginFrame)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(kAnimationTime, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: kAnimationDamping, initialSpringVelocity: kAnimationSpringVelocity, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations:
        { () -> Void in
            DLog(endFrame)
            popupView.frame = endFrame
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

in both cases it shows in console:

(72.5, -155.0, 230.0, 155.0)

(72.5, 256.0, 230.0, 155.0)

EDIT2

`setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)`

[image: set-false]

`setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(true)`

[image: set-true]

Comment: Refer this url : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29621114/method-presentviewcontroller-does-not-work-on-ios-8-3-after-update/29621571#29621571

Comment: @Rahul it's not the case - I'm not using standard  `UIAlertView` nor 'UIAlertController` - I'm replacing them with my custom `UIView` and showing logic in `UIViewController`'s extension

Comment: Could you maybe use liceCap to provide us with a gif? :) http://www.cockos.com/licecap/

Comment: Hmm. That's strange. I would suggest going through every line (or close to it) between when you instantiate the popover and when it gets animated, checking to see if its origin is (0,0) at any points. Sorry I don't have a better suggestion than that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got solution. I've stopped mixing autolayout and direct frame modifications and use pure autolayout instead.